# Graficos con Highcharts, JSON y CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, mvc, highcharts

Alguien que me ayude como hacer una Grafica utilizando Highcharts en CodeIgniter mediante JSON.

```
url:('<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/ejemplo/ejemDatos/datos', function (data) {

// create the chart

  Highcharts.stockChart('datos', { //datos es el id de mi `div` 

      rangeSelector: {
          selected: 1
      },

      title: {
          text: 'Ejemplo'
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Nº Datos',
          data: nDatos, // nDatos es el resultado de mi JSON
          tooltip: {

          }
      }]
    });
});
```

Así es como yo "pensaba" pero lo unico que me hace es poner el `div` en blanco, Alguien que me pueda ayudar.

> La libreri ya se encuentra cargada.

Comment: Inspecciona el elemento cuando, para así ver lo que está generando.

Comment: No he usado *CodeIgniter* pero sí Highchart y por lo regular esquema similar al que usas en **function(data)** *data* representa lo recibidos y usted tiene **data:ndatos,** mira cambiar (para evitar mismo nombre) **function(respuesta)** y **data:respuesta,**.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas, la situcacion es que mi JSON tiene mas de un dato tiene, usNom, usEdad, usGenero y y cambie como me dijiste **data:respuesta** y me dice ` Unexpected token :` entonces no se como es, no se si me explique y me puedas ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Buen día.

Realice un reemplazo de lo que pones con el ejemplo [Single line series](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line) abriendo del mismo el ejemplo que se proporciona (en el **jsfiddle**):

El original:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

lo "deje" (usando la parte que colocaste):

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', { //datos es el id de mi `div` 

  rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
  },

  title: {
      text: 'Ejemplo'
  },

  series: [{
      name: 'Nº Datos',
      data: data, // nDatos es el resultado de mi JSON
      tooltip: {

      }
  }]
});
```

y no hubo problema; la gráfica fue generada. Al parecer Highcharts o javascript (no se quien lo resuelva) identifica perfectamente si *data* es la propiedad/dato del Highchart o el parámetro (que en tu caso debe contener el JSON) por tanto a lo que inicialmente planteaste bastara que `url:('<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/ejemplo/ejemDatos/datos', function (data)` lo pongas como `url:('<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/ejemplo/ejemDatos/datos', function (nDatos)` o cambiar a `nDatos` como `data` alguna de las 2 como mejor prefieras.

En relación a que su JSON tiene más de un dato; puede ser algo en el mismo. Si te refieres a que son varias series te sugiero mires cumple con el formato para generar dichas [series](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cline%3E.data). Debes revisar tu JSON por cada serie cumple con lo aceptable por el Highchart puede ser algo en tu JSON (del cual no comparte la estructura *-no datos reales-* estructura para checar si hay algo de más o menos).